# Error 1711 under Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation, installer

I read a lot of stuff about the famous 1711 error, which means that during an installation process, installation data could not be written.

This can be due to a full harddisk, but also due to the namespace of `C:\Windows\Installer\msiXXXX.tmp` files being exhausted, where XXXX are hex digits.

Possible solutions include

- emptying temporary directories
- removing the said `msiXXXX.tmp`

None of them worked for me.

Does anybody know what could be the reason for these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of my problem.

While it was a silly mistake on my side, other poeple might stumble over it as well.

My `C:\Windows\Installer` lives in a separate partition, which was full. I didn't see that, as I just loooked at `C:\`, which had plenty of space at the same time. Extending this (dynamic) partition solved the problem.